# Prevent preg_replace replacing special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to linkify a twitter post. But hashtags that look like "#löövet" doesn't get filter as I want them to. They get cut off before the foreign characters. The foreign characters should be allowed.

Anyone know how to alter the regex for this purpose?

Below is my example:

```
//Hashtag
$tweet = preg_replace("/ +#([a-z0-9_]*)?/i", " <a href=\"http://twitter.com/tag/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $tweet);



//Problem: 
/*
* The function above does not match foreign characters as å/ä/ö
* Tag result example: tag = #löövet
* After preg_replace: tag = #l öövet
* Desired after preg_replace: tag = #löövet
*/
```

Comment: Adding the **u** flag to the pattern might work if you're using UTF-8 encoding. Of course, since you've explicitly listed just the unaccented Latin alphabet (a-z and A-Z), that's all you're going to get in this case. See other answers about using Unicode-enabled codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$tweet = preg_replace("/ +#(\p{Xwd}*)/u", " <a href=\"http://twitter.com/tag/$1\" target=\"_blank\">#$1</a>", $tweet);
```

`\p{Xwd}` has the same meaning that `\w` with all unicode letters and number and underscores.

If you don't want underscore, use `\p{Xan}`.

Comment: You have a typo `"/ +#(\p{Xwd]*)/u"` should be `"/ +#(\p{Xwd}*)/u"`. Curly brace instead of bracket. This seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

use \p{L} instead of a-z to match all unicode letters (or \p{L}\p{N} with numbers)

```
$tweet = preg_replace("/ +#([\p{L}\p{N}_]*)?/i", " <a href=\"http://twitter.com/tag/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $tweet);
```

to find more about unicode in regexp look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: That returns `#l��v` And the link is broken before the first `�`. I'm using UTF-8 throughout my project

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running behind the unicode, you can try this one if your hashtags do not contains any space.

```
/ +#(\S+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit allowed letters to latin letters, you can use:

```
$tweet = preg_replace('/ +#([\p{Latin}0-9_]*)/u', ' <a href="http://twitter.com/tag/$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>", $tweet);
```